# The direct sum is a subobject of the product in an abelian category

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

Let $\Lambda$ be a (not necessarily finite) set. If $(M_\lambda)_{\lambda\in \Lambda}$ is a family of modules, there is a morphism $i:\bigoplus_{\lambda\in \Lambda}(M_\lambda)\to \prod_{\lambda\in \Lambda}(M_\lambda)$. In a generic abelian category, how do you show that $i$ is monic?

Call $i_\lambda:\bigoplus_{\lambda\in \Lambda}(M_\lambda)\to M_\lambda$ the morphism such that $i_\lambda \iota_\mu$ is the Kronecker delta, with $\mu\in\Lambda$ and $\iota_\mu :M_\mu\to \bigoplus_{\lambda\in \Lambda}(M_\lambda)$ canonical. The aim is to prove that, if $f:N\to \bigoplus_{\lambda\in \Lambda}(M_\lambda)$ satisfies $i_\lambda f=0$ for all $\lambda$, then $f=0$. I couldn't prove it because the condition of an arrow, *into* a direct sum, being zero can't be translated in anything else by the universal properties at stake. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hint: show that each $i_\lambda$ is mono. This is easy if you define it through the universal property of $\oplus$.

Comment: I also would suggest (as this holds a lot more general) that you try to do it without using zero but using the definition of monic via cancelation! (it being monic should come directly from diagrams and cocones and cones)

Comment: @DanielTeixeira but, also in a category of modules, $i_\lambda$ maps $\sum_{\mu\in \Lambda}m_\mu$ to $m_\lambda\in M_\lambda$, so it is not injective. Am I wrong anywhere?

Comment: You're right, my mistake there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you couldn't prove it is that it is not true.

In particular, if your abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ is the opposite category of a module category $\operatorname{Mod}R$, then the coproduct in $\mathcal{A}$ is the product in $\operatorname{Mod}R$, and the product in $\mathcal{A}$ is the coproduct in $\operatorname{Mod}R$. The natural morphism "coproduct in $\mathcal{A}$ to product in $\mathcal{A}$" is just the natural module homomorphism $i:\bigoplus_{\lambda\in \Lambda}(M_\lambda)\to \prod_{\lambda\in \Lambda}(M_\lambda)$ considered as a morphism from $\prod_{\lambda\in \Lambda}(M_\lambda)$ to $\bigoplus_{\lambda\in \Lambda}(M_\lambda)$ in the opposite category $\mathcal{A}$.

But $i$ is monic but usually not epic in $\operatorname{Mod}R$, so is epic but usually not monic when considered as a morphism in the opposite category.